# How to copy skype user id with windows version of skype?

Tags: skype

This should be e pretty easy question.

I want to copy my friends' skype. I click profile. Double click the profile id. Tada I can't select or copy that to clipboard.

So there is no easy way to forward skype id to friends/

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10220/how-can-i-send-a-contact-s-details-to-another-contact-in-skype-for-windows-desktop) of any use to you? basically you send contact details, via IM or in Call by using the + sign, send contact

Comment: cool. Still can't copy that id but this will do